# How to highlight calendar cells based on given start and end date

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts, conditional-formatting

For a while now, a coworker has been using a chart similar to the one shown below and wants to automate it (i've already added the days before/after due date).

[image: worksheet screen capture]

The chart is printed or worked on at the computer by "painting" the cells that represent the start/end/possible end dates, and the ones between them. Is there a way to automate that process by inputting the dates, and possibly showing late or early final dates in a different color?

To clarify, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atsra.jpg) is what I want the end result to look like.
Each row represents a project, all of them starting on 9/8/2014 and (ideally) ending on 9/20/2014. The first row's project was completed five days early, the second ends two days late, the last ends on time, and Excel gives the cells the appropiate conditional formatting.

Comment: Edited to show what I'd want it to be like.

Answer (score 1):

The first posted answer is definitely correct: the solution is to use conditional formatting. 
Beyond that, it gets a bit hard to understand. 
So this answer may, at some level, be technically equivalent to Brian’s,
but with more of an emphasis on clarity; this answer:

- Identifies the rows and columns in the text in addition to the image.
- Displays dates in unambiguous format (hint: nn/nn/yyyy is ambiguous). 
  Unfortunately, that requires using month names in some language, so of course I used English.
- Uses the date values, colors, and layout used by the question.

The day numbers in Row 4 are actually date values,
formatted using the Custom format “d” (date number without leading zero) in English:

[image: value 8/8/2014 appears as “8”]
                [image: Custom format “d”]

If you just have the numbers 1-31 in Row 4,
then use `DATE(2014, 8, F$4)` instead of `F$4` in the formulas below.

Set conditional formats on cell `F5` (the first calendar/tasking cell of the chart) as follows:

- If `=(F$4<$B5)`, no format (or white fill), Stop If True
- If `=AND(F$4<=$C5, F$4<=$D5)`, fill blue
- If `=AND(F$4<=$C5, F$4>$D5)`, fill green
- If `=AND(F$4>$C5, F$4<=$D5)`, fill red

where

- `F$4` is the date corresponding to the current cell.
- `$B5` is the start date for the current task (row).
- `$C5` is the scheduled end date for the current task.
- `$D5` is the actual end date for the current task.

Then select cell `F5` and drag/fill out to the lower right column of the calendar area. 
It should look something like this:

[image: Conditional Formatting Rules Manager]

(Unfortunately, I can’t expand the Rule/Formula column to show the conditional formulas.)

Result looks like:

[image: results]
    <sup>[[The above image, and this text, link to a complete copy of the same image.]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EK6LN.png)</sup>

I had to change the color of cell `T5` (first task, ending early on 15-Aug)
because having it green (as in your image) didn’t seem to be consistent with the other rules. 
If you can figure out how to tweak the rules to get a better result, be my guest.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Conditional Formatting

For the Yellow part the Formula would be:`=AND($C3>=$D3,E3>=$D3,E3<=$C3)`

in the dates 01,02,03... I actually have 01/10/2014, 02/10/2014, etc... and Number format as just "mm"
(day above you can get using day(E1))

Can you implement this?

[image]

For the Red Part, use: `=AND($C3<$D3,E3>$C3,E3<=$D3)`

For the Green Part, use: `=AND($C3>=$D3,E3>=$D3,E3<=$C3)`

Answer (score 0):

I followed this to the letter but changed the obvious cell letter and number, but it does not work. My start date is 06.may.2022 and the end date is 01. november.2022 (Written like this 06.05.2022 and 01.11.2022, Norwegian excel) It only colours from 01.june.2022 and to 31.desember.2022. What am i doing wrong? I only want to highlight the cells in that row from the start date to the end date. Any suggestions?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1123486)

Answer (score 0):

I think the original poster just wants the classic conditional formatting for a column based on date

I would create a current week cell (D1) - you will manually edit this each week
Then highlight your entire gaant chart, with the dates as the top row
Then add conditional formatting (use a formulas to determine...)
=A$3=$D$1 (this is saying starting in cell A3 look to see if the date matched the date in D1)
you could then add a red border and color cells yellow (nice and bright!)

Where we DON'T complete his ask is that he doesn't want the new yellow fill color to overwrite any existing color, otherwise we can't see the projects that are active for any current week.

So anyone know how to add an extra condition. Like fill all cells with yellow - UNLESS the cell is already filled?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1128693)